# How do I delete the next line in vim?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, text-editing

In emacs, whenever I want to delete a few lines of text, I just use C-k until all the text is gone.  However, in vim it seems a bit more complex.  I know I can do `d$` to delete until the end of the line and `dd` to delete the entire line I'm on, but how do I delete all of the *next* line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Like this:

```
:+1d
```

Answer (score 17):

*Assumption: You want to end up at the line you started on.*

My answer: `jddk`

- j (moves down)
- dd (deletes current line)
- k (moves up)

Try it – it's quick!  In fact, it's **two** keystrokes less than the currently accepted answer because:

1. you don't need to hold `[Shift]` to enter the colon ':' and plus '+' characters, and
2. you don't need the implied `[Enter]` at the end of the sequence, since `jddk` is entered all in **visual mode** as opposed to **command mode**.

Plus, `jddk` is all on **home row** of the keyboard.

I spent a long time using **h, j, k, l** to navigate in `vi`, long before the terminal emulation software I used started supporting arrow keys.  (I'm talking about ~20 years ago ;-)

Comment: hjkl is faster anyway.  I've never used a keyboard that didn't have arrow keys on it, and I began to greatly value the efficacy of these keymappings about 10 minutes after I stopped being annoyed at the unintuitiveness of them.

Answer (score 4):

I strongly recommend reading this answer in stack overflow, which got over 500 upvotes:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1218390/what-is-your-most-productive-shortcut-with-vim/1220118#1220118  -- the answer is long, but helps to understand why vim is powerful...

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  Very thorough and informative answer about grokking vim and vi.

Answer (score 2):

You may also be interested in visual mode. Just use `v` to enter and `y` to yank or `d` to delete. Checking `:help` is a great place when you're stuck as well. For instance `:help delete` will give you the manual for most of the usual delete commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete a bunch of lines in a row, you can use `dd` to delete the line you're on, then keep hitting (or hold down) `.` (period) to repeat the command.

Comment: or type *Ndd* where *N* is the number of lines to delete.  say, to delete the current line and the next two lines (3 total), type **3dd**